# How to combine jQuery DataTables and SpringBoot JPA Pagination

Tags: spring-boot, datatables, pagination

I have a simple program that uses jQuery DataTables to search and filter database data, however, when using DataTables pagination all of the data stored in the database is loaded. This is a problem because if a database has over 20,000 rows of data the webpages' loading times would increase significantly.

Therefore I want to keep most of the DataTable functionalities like filtering and sorting but not pagination. I want to use JPA pagination(https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) for switching between pages as this would only load for example 10 rows of data at a time thus reducing loading times.

The following project is created with Java and the Spring project, it has filtering, sorting and pagination, as I mentioned I want to keep the pagination but use DataTables for the filtering and sorting.

**Employee.java**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    public String getGender(){return gender;}

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    // display list of employees
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model, @Param("keyword") String keyword) {
        return findPaginated(1, "firstName", "asc", keyword, model);
    }

    @GetMapping("/showNewEmployeeForm")
    public String showNewEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "new_employee";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        // save employee to database
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable ( value = "id") long id, Model model) {

        // get employee from the service
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);

        // set employee as a model attribute to pre-populate the form
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "update_employee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteEmployee/{id}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable (value = "id") long id) {
        // call delete employee method
        this.employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }


    @GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                @RequestParam(value = "sortField") String sortField,
                                @RequestParam(value = "sortDir", defaultValue = "asc") String sortDir,
                                @RequestParam(value = "keyword", required = false) String keyword,
                                Model model) {
        int pageSize = 10;
        Sort.Direction direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeService.searchEmployees(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir, keyword);
        } else {
            page = employeeService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        }
        List<Employee> listEmployees = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", listEmployees);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.firstName LIKE %?1%")
    public List<Employee> findAll(String keyword);

    //Used for search filter
    Page<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(String keyword, String keyword1, Pageable pageable);

}
```

**EmployeeService.java**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {
    List<Employee> findAll(String keyword);
    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();
    void saveEmployee(Employee employee);
    Employee getEmployeeById(long id);
    void deleteEmployeeById(long id);
    Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection);

    Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword);
//  Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword);
}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl.java**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll(String keyword) {
        return employeeRepository.findAll(keyword);
    }

    public Employee get(Long id) {
        return employeeRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        Optional<Employee> optional = employeeRepository.findById(id);
        Employee employee = null;
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            employee = optional.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(" Employee not found for id :: " + id);
        }
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(long id) {
        this.employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }



    public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
        Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
            Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
        return this.employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public Page<Employee> searchEmployees(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDir, String keyword) {
        Sort sort = Sort.by(sortField);
        sort = sortDir.equals("asc") ? sort.ascending() : sort.descending();

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);

        Page<Employee> page;
        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            page = employeeRepository.findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(keyword, keyword, pageable);
        } else {
            page = employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
        }

        return page;
    }
}
```

Lastly this is the **index.html** page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Management System</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container my-2">
    <h1>Employees List</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/}">
            Filter: <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="50" th:value="${keyword}" required />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClear" onclick="clearSearch()" />
        </form>
        Sort by email: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="email"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>
        <br>
        Sort by lastname: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="lastName"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>
        <br>
        Sort by firstname: <form th:action="@{/page/1}" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="sortField" value="firstName"/>
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="asc" th:checked="${sortDir=='asc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Ascending
            <input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="desc" th:checked="${sortDir=='desc'}" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> Descending
        </form>

        <a th:href = "@{/showNewEmployeeForm}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"> Add Employee </a><br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="female-checkbox">
            <label for="female-checkbox">Show All Employees</label>
        </div>
        <table border="1" class = "table table-striped table-responsive-md">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=firstName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                        Employee First Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=lastName&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Last Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <a th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=email&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}}">
                            Employee Email</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Gender
<!--                        <label for="showFemaleEmployeesCheckbox">Show Female Employees</label>-->
<!--                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="showAll()" id="showAllCheckbox"> Show all genders-->
                    </th>
                    <th> Actions </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="employee : ${listEmployees}">
                <td th:text="${employee.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.lastName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.email}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.gender}"></td>
                <td>
                    <a th:href="@{/showFormForUpdate/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/deleteEmployee/{id}(id=${employee.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div th:if = "${totalPages > 1}">
            <div class = "row col-sm-10">
                <div class = "col-sm-2">
                    Total Rows: [[${totalItems}]]
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}" style="display: flex;">
                        <a th:if="${currentPage != i}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${i}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                        <span th:unless="${currentPage != i}">[[${i}]]</span>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Next</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${totalPages}+ '?sortField=' + ${sortField} + '&sortDir=' + ${sortDir}}">Last</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearSearch() {
        window.location = "[[@{/}]]";
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=radio][name=sortField]').change(function() {
          $('#sortField').val(this.id);
          $('form').submit();
        });
    });

    let employees = [];

    // Loop through each row in the table body
    document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(row => {
      // Check if the row is for a male employee
      if (row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').textContent === 'M') {
        // Add the employee data to the array
        employees.push({
          firstName: row.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)').textContent,
          lastName: row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent,
          email: row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent,
          gender: row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').textContent,
          id: row.querySelector('td:last-child a:first-child').getAttribute('href').match(/\d+/)[0]
        });
      }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get all female employees
  var femaleEmployees = $('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text() === 'F';
  });

  // Hide female employees by default
  femaleEmployees.hide();

  // Toggle female employees when checkbox is clicked
  $('#female-checkbox').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      femaleEmployees.show();
      localStorage.setItem('female-checkbox', true);
    } else {
      femaleEmployees.hide();
      localStorage.setItem('female-checkbox', false);
    }
  });

  // Check the checkbox based on localStorage value
  var checkboxState = localStorage.getItem('female-checkbox');
  if (checkboxState === 'true') {
    $('#female-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    femaleEmployees.show();
  } else {
    $('#female-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    femaleEmployees.hide();
  }
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I want to implement pagination at the controller level and not in the front-end.